# rasterize cells of tableview only when scrolling in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a tableview that has pretty graphics (round corners, transparent cells using clearcolor() etc.) I'm also using maskToBounds so the only way to make the scrolling smooth is to set the layer.shouldRasterize = true.
This works fine but when I delete a cell or drag a cell to move and rearrange I see "artifacts" mostly the cells loose their transparency for a split second in my tableview because the cell is updating it's content from the rasterize

I'd like to rasterize the tableviewcells only when I'm scrolling it so I tried various methods including a very dirty method where I rasterize to true as soon as the tableView.contentOffset.y changes and then delaying it for a second to simulate the time it takes for scrolling and setting it back to false.

```c
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
  cell.textLabel?.text = cellitemcontent[indexPath.row]
  //here I have all the custom cell design...

   var currentOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    if currentOffset > 0
    { cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true}
    else{
        delay(1.5){
        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = false

        }
    }
   return cell
}
```

Can someone point me to a cleaner way to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have the properties

```
weak var tableView : UITableView!
var isScrolling = false
```

and as the UITableViewDelegate protocol extends UIScrollViewDelegate, I would implement

```
func visibleCellsShouldRasterize(aBool:Bool){
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells() as [UITableViewCell]{
        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = aBool;
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isScrolling = false
    self.visibleCellsShouldRasterize(isScrolling)
}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if velocity == CGPointZero{
        isScrolling = false
        self.visibleCellsShouldRasterize(isScrolling)
    }
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isScrolling = true
    self.visibleCellsShouldRasterize(isScrolling)

}
```

to switch shouldRasterize for visible cells and for cells coming to screen, I would implement

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = isScrolling
}
```